# SQL Server 2000 SQL HANDLE returning empty result set

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

My session in sql server management studio is 67. I put the following query in the window, note that I am querying a sql server 2000 database .

```
DECLARE @Handle varbinary(64);
SELECT @Handle = sql_handle 
FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses 
WHERE spid ='67';
select @Handle
SELECT * FROM ::fn_get_sql(@Handle);
GO
```

I get the sql handle  0x01000D00E005B614C0A094720000000000000000 but can get the sql from it .

I have full permissions on that database .

What am I doing wrong ? Do I need to install 2008 management studio ?

Comment: DBCC INPUTBUFFER (58) works but only gives you the first 255 characters

Comment: The query tool version (Query Analyzer or SSMS) doesn't matter since it just sends the script to the server.  I don't have a SQL 2000 instance to test this on but you might try declaring @Handle as binary(20) instead of varbinary.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That still returns an empty result set so does not unfortunately does not solve my problem.